# Swift Center UIActivityIndicatorView on UISplitViewController detail controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `UIActivityIndicatorView` inside the `UISplitViewController`'s detail view and its not centering, its more aligned to the right, here is my code that adds the `UIActivityIndicatorView`:

```
indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

        //Set the activity indicator center

        indicator.center = self.view.center

        //Hide the indicator when its stopped.

        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

        //Set the style of the activity indicator

        indicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.white

        //Set the background colour of the activity indicator

        indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.6)

        //Make the activity indicator have rounded corners

        indicator.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        //Add activity indicator to view

        self.view.addSubview(indicator)

        //Start activity indicator

        self.indicator.startAnimating()
```

How come its not centering?

Comment: could it be because you're trying to set the width/height to a 100? Because it already has an intrinsic content size. Perhaps try initialising it as UIActivityIndicatorView() and just adjusting the center

Comment: By just doing this: indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView() nothing appears.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid instancing a `UIActivityIndicatorView` with a frame and instead use this initializer:

> init(style: `UIActivityIndicatorView.Style`)

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview/):

> `UIActivityIndicatorView` sizes the returned instance according to the specified style. You can set and retrieve the style of a activity indicator through the `style` property.

So you should do something like this:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.myActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .white)
}

override viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.myActivityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code in the viewWillAppear func and it works... anyway if you want to use the other approach but keeping the rounded corner bg view:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    myActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .white)
    myActivityIndicatorView?.hidesWhenStopped = true
    myActivityBGView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    myActivityBGView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.6)
    myActivityBGView?.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    if let myActivityIndicatorView = myActivityIndicatorView,
        let myActivityBGView = myActivityBGView {
        myActivityBGView.addSubview(myActivityIndicatorView)
        view.addSubview(myActivityBGView)
        myActivityIndicatorView.center = myActivityBGView.center
        myActivityBGView.center = view.center
        myActivityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This centers my UIActivityIndicatorView

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        if(self.indicator != nil)
        {
            self.indicator.center = self.view.center
        }
    }
```